# Click event for computed listbox?

Tags: xpages

I am displaying an HTML list box using some computed fields and a repeat control.  It works great, including a pager which pages the list box selections.

Now I want an onclick event for the list box. The client side click event needs to populate a field.  My click event works fine but I can't figure out how to get a handle to the field.

In a client click event in designer, I could simply do something like:
     document.getElementById("#{id:lastSelected}").value = namesSelected;

but this does not appear to work for me as I am not really going through designer so #{id:lastSelected}  is not defined correct?

Is there anyway I can make my option line clickable so that I can add the event through the designer?

Or is there someway that "#{id:lastSelected}" can be resolved within my client javascript for the way I am doing it?  Maybe call an XSP function?

Here is the computed field that creates the first part of the listbox, notice how I am doing the onclick event.

```
 var id = "id='" + getClientId("searched") +"ListBox'";     //Generate a unique id for the list box using the computed field name   
 var size= "size=" + compositeData.listBoxSize.toString();  
 var style = "style='width:275px;'";
 var multi = (compositeData.multipleSelect==true) ? "multiple" : ""     
 return "<select " +id + " " + size + " " + style + " " + multi + " onclick='searchedListBoxSingleLeftClick();'>";
```

Here is how I compute each option line, this computed field is inside the repeat control

```
 var name = rowData.getColumnValues()[1]; 
 return "<option " + " id='" + rowData + "' value='" + rowData.getUniversalID() + "'>" + name + "</option>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bruce - just like in the Name Picker custom control I sent you, you can use a scriptBlock to surface the id of the component you need:

```
var lastSelected = "#{id:lastSelected}";
```

Then, in your client javascript you can reference that variable:

```
dojo.byId(lastSelected).value = namesSelected
```

Comment: Thanks I will take a look.  What happens if you have more that one CC on ur form at the same time?   Won't they both use the same lastSelected?

Comment: No .. they are self contained in that custom control.

Comment: My cs script function should go in the block too?  If I do this and do not use an extension pages db then it works fine.  If I put my cc inside a dialog box then it fails, seems it can't find the function.

Comment: Got it working.   I had my script block on the custom control so the block was not being rendered when the browser was first displayed.  I put the block in it's own custom control and placed that along with my name picker on my page.  Works fantastic!   Thanks for your help.